Finding true color formula using bad color-match and reference
My local home improvement store attempted to color-match a paint sample I provided, but the result turned out to be off significantly. The color-matched paint looks "wet" and darker than the rest of the wall.
I'd like to know if it's possible to fix this color match and find the true color, by determining the difference RGB between the two colors in the image, and using this to adjust the color formula, in order to avoid having to paint the entire wall.
So far these are the datapoints I have:

Wrong paint pixel color RGB: (40.8, 37.6, 36.9)

Original color paint pixel color RGB: (43.5, 43.9, 45.9)

Wrong Paint Proprietary? Color forumla: Base B3704. Not sure how to read the rest of the values.


Is it possible to come up with a function to translate store-specific color formulas into something resembling RGB values?
Would it be possible to ask the store to adjust the existing color formula in specific ways? For example: increase red tint by 7%, green by 16% and blue by 24%?
If not, is there a DIY alternative for finding the true color of my wall's paint?



Colour matching is good for a few weeks/months after painting of same paint.  Sun fading, dust/dirt on the surface, time, makes matching much harder.  After some time, evening using the exact same paint colour will not match.  Usually painting the whole wall is much easier than small sections, and usually cheaper.

I dunno -- I've had startlingly good results with paint matching at home derpo... it might have been that the tiny sampler size (and the satin, where I'm guessing you want flat) screwed things up. I'd try again with a quart and take it back if you really don't like it.

Plus, if this was created last October, did you mix it thoroughly before use? Or did you paint back then?

It was painted back then. Maybe I will try again. I was just wondering if there's a more precise way to fix the situation given a reference.

Your best bet is to get some swatches of your selected paint line and eyeball a match.  Buy a sampler, try it out, and fine tune from there.

The absolutely best way to color match is with your Mark-1 Human Eyeballs. Instead of relying on the spectrometer, you should bring a sample (like a cover from one of those panels in the picture) to a paint shop and find a sample chip that most closely resembles it.
Note: even with the closest match possible it will never match exactly. That's why pros would never do a touch-up like the one in the picture; they would paint the entire area, ending at some logical break in the surface (e.g., a corner or perpendicular wall section.)

No that is not possible.
paint colour can't be decomposed to RGB values, as aparrent colour depends on the spectrum of the lighting. Also RGB  does not encode the gloss level of the paint.
Try a paint shop instead of home improvement.  they will likely have a color matching expert instead of an appliance operator.

My experience has been that the machine at Lowe's makes a better color match than any pro paint store around me, as long as I tell them the correct sheen.
